# Need help with JavaScript Regular Expression:Regular Expression Too Complex

Tags: javascript, regex

Following Regular expression `^[0-9A-Za-z]+(\s)*(-?(\s)*[0-9A-Za-z]+)*$` is matching for most of the cases like eg `"dsffsd-fdsfds-dasda"` but when i give string to be matched as `"dsffsd-fdsfds-dasda-dasdas--dasdas-dsfs"` im getting error in firebug saying Regular Expression Too Complex.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post a code throwing the *Regular Expression Too Complex* error on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: If your pattern is too complicated, use extended mode via `/x` or `(?x)` so you can read it by adding spaces for breathing room and comments for explanation: `^ [0-9A-Za-z]+ (\s)* ( -? (\s)* [0-9A-Za-z]+ ) * $`.  Plus I am pretty sure that that pattern is wrong: you have quantifiers around capture groups, like `(\s)*` for `(\s*)`. Also, `\w` is much more readable than `[0-9A-Za-z]`. In most regex engines (but not Javascript’s, which is the absolute worst of all regex engines), it is also more correct, too. Remember that `[A-Z]` is a strong antipattern that’s always wrong *sometimes*.

Comment: @tchrist Isn't "always wrong *sometimes*" an oxymoron?

Comment: I tried to answer. The question does lack a lot of details... Should that string be valid? Does the pattern really represent valid/invalid strings? What are other possible inputs and outputs?

Comment: @NullUserException: Not at all; it conveys exactly what it means to convey. Even though `[A-Z]` might work fine for a particular dataset and intent, there is always a different dataset where it fails to meet that same intention. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn’t. There is always a situation where it fails. So even if it seems to work in the here and now, that is only by accident and cannot be counted about. In the long run, therefore, it is always wrong, even if that always is only sometimes.  See?

Comment: @tchrist - It is awfully optimistic of you to think JavaScript supports the `/x` flag. It only has `/i`, `/g` and `/m`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp . I suppose it's possible to create a string-based regexp object, and use string concatenation and comments, similar to Java: `"\\w" + /* alphanumeric */ "\\d+" /* digits */`

Comment: @Kobi: Sigh. I said Javascript regexes were pessimal, didn’t I? :(

Answer (score 3):

The regex is falling under [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), which is the reason you get this error. Note that your string isn't matched by the pattern, since the pattern doesn't allow two hyphens: `--`.

I was able to simplify the pattern to:

```
/^\w(?:-?\s*\w)*$/
```

If I did this right, this pattern only allows one way of matching each string, so it shouldn't suffer the same problem.
If you don't need such constrains you can greatly simply the pattern, for example to `/^[\w\s\-]*$/`.
Note that `\w` also matched underscores, but it should be easy to correct if needed.

Comment: Hmm... I'm missing `a - b`. I'll think about that one. I think `/^\w(?:(?:\s*-)?\s*\w)*$/` should be good enough. Anyway, I'll be back in a few hours.